# Neo4j Cypher: control order of MATCH based on input array?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm writing a query that iterates over some set of nodes:

```
MATCH (foo:Bar)
WHERE foo.id IN {ids}
```

Is there any way for me to specify/require/ensure that the matched nodes be in the same order as the input `ids` array?

As an analogy, with Neo4j 1.x, this was the behavior with native ID lookups:

```
START foo=node({ids})
```

For trivial cases, I can always re-order the results on the client myself. In this particular case, my query does some additional processing, and I want to make sure the nodes get processed in the right order.

Here's a console example to experiment with:

http://console.neo4j.org/r/l5oouj

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UNWIND` to the rescue!

```
UNWIND {ids} AS id
MATCH (foo:Bar {id: id})
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/vit7c8

Comment: its fine, but in graph db this was suppose to be done with `relations` and not with matching against a `set`. consider rebuilding the database so these `ids` would have some specific relationships pattern, and so you could `match` them directly

Comment: Not sure what you mean @ulkas. These can still be an index lookup rather than a scan; and Neo4j 2.0 added first-class, constraint-based indexing to Cypher.

Comment: i meant just when using `unwind` too often, or as a primary query corpus, it indicates a wrong graph format. neo4j graph is all about nodes and vertices and the unwind parameter should be imported into the graph as a separate  node/rel, because its being used as a primary goal for querying.